# How to properly await createWriteStream?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Async programming in node.js is usually done with callbacks. I find callback-based code hard to read and reason about, which is why I'm using `async` & `await` whenever I can. This almost always works well and leads to robust code. However, rarely I'm wondering whether I'm making things more difficult than necessary. For example, how do you create a stream such that you can `await` its creation? More specifically, the result of the `await` should of course be the stream itself when things go well. When they don't, an appropriate exception should be thrown.

The best I could come up with is the function below. It feels very clunky and I'm wondering whether there is an easier way to do this?

```
import type { EventEmitter } from "events";

export const createStreamAsync = async <T extends EventEmitter>(create: () => T): Promise<T> => {
    const result = create();
    let onOpen = (): void => void 0;
    let onError = (reason?: unknown): void => void reason;

    try {
        await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            onOpen = resolve;
            onError = reject;
            result.on("open", onOpen).on("error", onError);
        });

        return result;
    } finally {
        result.removeListener("open", onOpen);
        result.removeListener("error", onError);
    }
};
```

You'd use the function as follows:

```
import { createWriteStream } from "fs";
import { createStreamAsync } from "./createStreamAsync.js";

try {
    const stream = await createStreamAsync(() => createWriteStream("~/whatever.txt"));
    // Use stream ...
} catch (error: unknown) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to handle exceptions thrown by `createWriteStream`. If an exception happens at creation time, there will be no stream returned to remove listeners from.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. WRT to removing listeners, do you refer to the `try`/`catch` in `createStreamAsync`?

Comment: I was talking about the `removeListener` calls in the `finally` block. Those are not necessary, and the `try...finally` around the code is not necessary.

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I understand `createWriteStream` does not throw when something goes wrong during file creation. Instead, you are supposed to listen to `"error"` event, correct? My code is convoluted, it appears @rickn solution is much easier to follow.

Comment: Exactly, it does not throw. That is why the `try...finally` block is unnecessary. Good luck!

Comment: Do we agree that the awaited promise inside the block can throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readable streams [have an `AsyncIterator` symbol](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/stream.html#readablesymbolasynciterator), so they can be processed with `for await ... of`:

```
const readable = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
for await (const chunk of readable) {
  console.log(chunk);
}
```

You can listen to both an event and catch the `error` event (if any) with [`events.once`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/events.html#eventsonceemitter-name-options):

```
const { once } = require('node:events');
const writable = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
try {
  await once(writable, 'open');
  // If the event emits data, `once` returns it as an array: 
  // const x = await once(...);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Could not open file', err);
}
```

This will automatically remove the listener, just like `EventEmitter.once` does.

`event.on` returns an AsyncIterator to handle multiple events:

```
const { on } = require('node:events');
const { exec } = require('node:child_process');
const child = exec(...);
try {
  for await (const event of on(child, 'message')) {
    // `event` is an array of 0 or more values.
    console.log(event);
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```